# SharePoint Workspace keeps running

Tags: workspace

Does anyone know how to keep Sharepoint Workspace from restarting after exiting?

I have disabled Preferences -> Options -> Startup Settings -> Launch

But still everytime I quit the application from the system tray, 10 seconds later it starts up again.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Run MSConfig.exe and remove it from startup items. Then it will not start when you reboot your computer, so will not keep restarting.

Comment: This will remove it from the computer's startup.  The OP wants to know how to keep it from restarting when he exits the program.